# Summing Every Other Element of a List/Turning Every Other Element Complex

Tags: python

Given a general list of numbers, say, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], I need to split this list into the form [(1 + 2j), (3 + 4j), (5 + 6j)].

I can split the list into two lists - [1, 3, 5] and [2, 4, 6] - but encounter two problems when attempting to combine them into the desired form: i) that I cannot multiply the second list by 1j, returning the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'", and ii) the list would be of the form [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6] anyway due to concatenation.

Given that I'm working with lists that have 2048 elements, could anybody suggest any quick solutions to this problem, as obviously the size makes individually inputting the data in the desired format impractical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `zip()` and slicing:

```
In [72]: lis=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [73]: [complex(a,b) for a,b in zip(lis[::2],lis[1::2])]
Out[73]: [(1+2j), (3+4j), (5+6j)]
```

or:

```
In [74]: [complex(lis[i],lis[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(lis),2)]
Out[74]: [(1+2j), (3+4j), (5+6j)]
```

or using an iterator, a memory efficient solution:

```
In [76]: it=iter(lis)

In [77]: [complex(next(it),next(it)) for _ in range(len(lis)/2)]
Out[77]: [(1+2j), (3+4j), (5+6j)]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Many, many thanks. I had tried using zip() but ended up with the form [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)] and had no idea about slicing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @docar glad that helped. But for large lists don't use slicing(zip+slicing) as it creates two lists in memory, and is also slower than the other two solutions.